# How to get the values from HBase table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I have a table in Hbase with one column family called `a`and around 30 columns in it. Below is a sample that shows cell values of two row keys-

```
ROW                                  COLUMN+CELL
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasbig, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasdel, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasdhq, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasfsc, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasgbm, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasgbr, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasmcu, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasser, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aastlp, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000574                        column=a:aasvia, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasbig, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasdel, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasdhq, timestamp=1486493154559, value=true
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasfsc, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasgbm, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasgbr, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasmcu, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasser, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aastlp, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
 00:001000707                        column=a:aasvia, timestamp=1486493154559, value=false
```

Each column has a value with either `true` or `false`. These values are subjected to change and week later the values may be different. I would like to capture the old and new values. The result should be stored in a CSV file.

My requirement is, when I run the code for the first time I should see the OLDVALUE as NULL and all the values from the HBase table should be a part of NEWVALUE.

Below is the output I want to see in a CSV file when run for the first time.

```
NUM,PRODUCT,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE
001000574,aasbig,NULL,true
001000574,aasdel,NULL,true
001000574,aasdhq,NULL,false
001000574,aasfsc,NULL,true
001000574,aasgbm,NULL,true
001000574,aasgbr,NULL,true
001000574,aasmcu,NULL,true
001000574,aasser,NULL,true
001000574,aastlp,NULL,true
001000574,aasvia,NULL,true
001000707,aasbig,NULL,false
001000707,aasdel,NULL,false
001000707,aasdhq,NULL,true
001000707,aasfsc,NULL,false
001000707,aasgbm,NULL,false
001000707,aasgbr,NULL,false
001000707,aasmcu,NULL,false
001000707,aasser,NULL,false
001000707,aastlp,NULL,false
001000707,aasvia,NULL,false
```

From Second time on wards when I run the code all the values in `NEWVALUES` from the previous run should now be under `OLDVALUES` and the `NEWVALUES` should get the current values from the HBase table. Like the below sample output

```
NUM,PRODUCT,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE
001000574,aasbig,true,true
001000574,aasdel,true,true
001000574,aasdhq,false,false
001000574,aasfsc,true,true
001000574,aasgbm,true,false
001000574,aasgbr,true,true
001000574,aasmcu,true,false
001000574,aasser,true,false
001000574,aastlp,true,true
001000574,aasvia,true,true
001000707,aasbig,false,true
001000707,aasdel,false,true
001000707,aasdhq,true,true
001000707,aasfsc,false,false
001000707,aasgbm,false,false
001000707,aasgbr,false,false
001000707,aasmcu,false,true
001000707,aasser,false,true
001000707,aastlp,false,false
001000707,aasvia,false,true
```

What I tried:
I created a Hive-on-Hbase table and while querying the table I was only able to get the `NUM` and the `value`. I was unable to get the HBase column name. Also I had challenges in getting the Old and New value unless I implement some join operations.

Can we write Pig script to achieve this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done programmatically by following steps:

1. For first time `Scan` the table and get its output. There are other optimized variants for this too.

   `Scan scan = new Scan();
   ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
   for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result =   scanner.next()){

     //Create required format
   }`
2. For next time `Scan` the table using `Range` filter providing `startTime` part time in the API. It will fetch all the records updated after a certain time period. `Result` will contain versions of the updated record. You can use last and recent version details and generate the output.

   `Scan scan = new Scan();
   scan.setTimeRange(startTime, endTime);
   ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
   for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result =    scanner.next()){
      NavigableMap<byte[],NavigableMap<byte[],NavigableMap<Long,byte[]>>> allVersions=result.getMap(); 
      //allVersions map will give all versions of the record.
      //Create required format
   }`

   I am not sure about Hive or Pig process for this. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you edit your answer and illustrate with some examples please?